# Are LINQ-returned IEnumerables "cast-hack" free?

Tags: linq, ienumerable

Are `IEnumerable`s returned by LINQ methods such as `Select` or  `SelectMany` "cast-hack" free? For instance, you can return from a function whose output type is `IEnumerable` an `IList`, but if you cast it back to `IList` you will be able to modify it. Does the same happen with `IEnumerable`s returned by LINQ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The LINQ methods return special iterator collection classes that wrap the original data source or employ the `yield` keyword. The reason is deferred execution.

For example:

- `Select` and `Where` return an instance of the private class `WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<TSource, TResult>`.
- `Except` and `Distinct` use the `yield` keyword to return the elements from the collections that match the condition.

You can use [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ilspy.ashx) to have a look at this code yourself.